# As there is no officical docs for php with ReQl , can you please show the PHP equivalent of :

Tags: php, rethinkdb, reql

Basically I have an array in the format: `array('context_text'=>some_value,'name'=>some_value,'target'=>{..});`

I need to add another value to the target index like:

`array('context_text'=>some_value,'name'=>some_value,'target'=>{..},{...},{...});`

What is the equivalent ReQl code for PHP for this?

Comment: You can find some basic PHP ReQL documentation here => http://danielmewes.dnsalias.net/~daniel/php-rql-api/

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I got my answers here . They should provide this link after the ReQl driver installation for PHP in the official docs .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question, but here goes the answer, at least an attempt:

```
$myArray = array('context_text'=>some_value,'name'=>some_value,'target'=>array('key1' => some_value, 'key2' => some_value));
```

Basically, you nest an associative `array` as an element of your associative `array`. If you want to add an element later, you can do something like this:

```
$myArray['target']['key3']  = some_value;
```

Comment: I got that ,but I need to perform this as a query in RethinkDb . The problem is there are no official support for RethinkDb query in PHP .